# Get a part of a list and change the original when the new list changes

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I want to know if it's possible do that:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
b = a[2:]
b[0] = -1
print(a)
print(b)
```

and get this:

```
[0, 1, -1, 3, 4]
[-1, 3, 4]
```

Normally, you will get this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[-1, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Your question is unclear... You provided a code and its output, now, what would you *like* it to do that it currently doesn't ?

Comment: So you want `a` and `b` to point to the same list object and update together?

Comment: Yes, I do. The problem's you get a copy when you slice the original list. I need when I change 'b' changes 'a'.

Comment: add a line, `a[2] = -1` before
`print(a)`?

Comment: @downshift He apparently doesn't want to hard code it. He wants the update to happen automatically.

Comment: ah ok, i'm a hardheaded coder. thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: But if I do that I must made the changes two times... The idea is change only 'b' and changes 'a' automatically.

Comment: might want to edit the "little" in title to that which *actually* changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, with plain `list`s this is not possible because slicing returns a shallow copy of the slice.

However if you have NumPy it's possible because there slices of an `array` return views not copies:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
b = a[2:]
b[0] = -1
print(a)   # [ 0  1 -1  3  4]
print(b)   # [-1  3  4]
```

Answer (score 4):

Briefly explain what I understand this, let me know if I make any mistakes.

The answer is NO.

In python, the variable is a tag linked to the object. 
If we do

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
b = a
id(a) #199598920
id(b) #199598920
```

The `b` is just a name tag name linked to the object.It shares the same object with `a`

[image]

---

To your question,

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
id(a) #199598920
a[2:] # [2, 3, 4]
id(a[2:]) #199581576
```

`a[2:]` gives us a slice of a list by creating a new list and copying a part of the first list into the new list.

[image]

In this case, you cannot automatically update you `b[0]` and list `a`

Comment: I understood. It's not possible, I need coded it. Thank you !

Comment: Comparing the `id` of the original and the slice isn't conclusive - because even if they would share the underlying "data" the id has to be different (simply because one instance can't represent itself and a slice of itself). Otherwise great answer - I really like the images! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that? ;)

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
b = a[2:]
b[0] = a[2] = -1 
print(a)
print(b)
```